# How to make sequential execution of setTimeout in this example?

Tags: javascript, async-await, settimeout

I'm trying to implement this code in such a way that the first function with its setTimeout is executed first, and then the second. But it turns out that due to asynchrony, all map iterations are processed and callbacks from setTimeout are placed in the queue, which are executed in parallel with setTimeout callbacks inside another function. How can I fix this behaviour?

```
const matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

async function displayHorizontalPatterns() {
  console.log("HORIZONTAL start");

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    matrix.map((el, idx) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        el.fill(1);
        console.log(matrix);
        el.fill(0);
      }, idx * 1000);
    });
    resolve();
  });

  console.log("HORIZONTAL end");
}

displayHorizontalPatterns();
```

Comment: do you really need `map`? [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if I understand correctly that you should put the `await new Promise(` inside the map making it `.map(async(el, idx...` and then putting the resolve inside the timeout. Lastly to wait for all these promises wrap everything in `await Promise.all`. Getting something like this.

```
await Promise.all(matrix.map(async (el, idx) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            el.fill(1);
            console.log(matrix);
            el.fill(0);
            resolve();
        }, idx * 1000);
    });
});
```